# Why are all build statuses on Monero's Github failing?

Tags: monerod, github

Should I use a Debian distro with an armv8 architecture if I am looking for stability?

[image: Build Statuses on .README Page]

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that the crypto tests include a set of expected values from the pseudo random number generator, which was recently changed to remove a tiny bias, thereby changing the returned values. A patch which was supposed to update the values did not actually fix it, and another needs to be made instead.

The Windows platforms were also broken for a couple days near your post's date when the block/tx notifications went in as they tried to build the POSIX code.

At least one of the ARM build machines is also missing some necessary libraries and needs updating.

Answer (score 0):

Because the build bots need some loving attention. They've been like this for a few months now, while people have been busy on other things.

Comment: Doesn't that signal some instability as well? My monerod (windows distro) is frequently crashing - should I use Debian?

Comment: It's the build bots, not Monero. If you are having some crashing, report a GitHub issue please.